# Non-tail recursion and argument expansion order

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion, recursion

I'm having a trouble understanding the expansion order of TeX macros:

```
\newcount\x

\def\dec#1{%
  \ifnum#1=0
    .%
  \else
    #1%
    \x=#1
    \advance\x by-1
    \dec{\number\x}%
    #1%
  \fi%
}
\dec{5}

\bye
```

The above non-tail recursion results in `54321.00005`, instead of `54321.12345`.
I understand that what I want can be achieved by restoring `\x` after the recursive `\dec` expansion.
However, I do not quite get why this results in `00005`.

Can someone enlighten me?
Thank you.

Comment: please post code in a form that can be run. Presumably  x is defined by `\newcount\x` ??

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\newcount\x

\def\dec#1{%
  \ifnum#1=0
    .%
  \else
    #1%
    \x=#1
    \advance\x by-1
    \dec{\number\x}%
    #1%
  \fi%
}

{\tracingmacros1 \tracingonline1
\dec{5}
}
\bye
```

produces

```
\dec #1->\ifnum #1=0 .\else #1\x =#1 \advance \x by-1 \dec {\number \x }#1\fi 
#1<-5

\dec #1->\ifnum #1=0 .\else #1\x =#1 \advance \x by-1 \dec {\number \x }#1\fi 
#1<-\number \x 

\dec #1->\ifnum #1=0 .\else #1\x =#1 \advance \x by-1 \dec {\number \x }#1\fi 
#1<-\number \x 

\dec #1->\ifnum #1=0 .\else #1\x =#1 \advance \x by-1 \dec {\number \x }#1\fi 
#1<-\number \x 

\dec #1->\ifnum #1=0 .\else #1\x =#1 \advance \x by-1 \dec {\number \x }#1\fi 
#1<-\number \x 

\dec #1->\ifnum #1=0 .\else #1\x =#1 \advance \x by-1 \dec {\number \x }#1\fi 
#1<-\number \x
```

so you see that you are not passing in different values each time, every argument is `\number \x` so at the end you have multiple `\number\x`  so they all print 0

---

You can expand `\number` before recursing

```
\newcount\x

\def\dec#1{%
  \ifnum#1=0
    .%
  \else
    #1%
    \x=#1
    \advance\x by-1
    \expandafter\dec\expandafter{\number\x}%
    #1%
  \fi%
}

{\tracingmacros1 \tracingonline1
\dec{5}
}
\bye
```

Produces

```
\dec #1->\ifnum #1=0 .\else #1\x =#1 \advance \x by-1 \expandafter \dec \expand
after {\number \x }#1\fi 
#1<-5

\dec #1->\ifnum #1=0 .\else #1\x =#1 \advance \x by-1 \expandafter \dec \expand
after {\number \x }#1\fi 
#1<-4

\dec #1->\ifnum #1=0 .\else #1\x =#1 \advance \x by-1 \expandafter \dec \expand
after {\number \x }#1\fi 
#1<-3

\dec #1->\ifnum #1=0 .\else #1\x =#1 \advance \x by-1 \expandafter \dec \expand
after {\number \x }#1\fi 
#1<-2

\dec #1->\ifnum #1=0 .\else #1\x =#1 \advance \x by-1 \expandafter \dec \expand
after {\number \x }#1\fi 
#1<-1

\dec #1->\ifnum #1=0 .\else #1\x =#1 \advance \x by-1 \expandafter \dec \expand
after {\number \x }#1\fi 
#1<-0
```

[image]

---

With etex (including pdftex, luatex, xetex, ...) You do not need `\x`

```
\def\dec#1{%
  \ifnum#1=0
    .%
  \else
    #1%
    \expandafter\dec\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1-1\relax}%
    #1%
  \fi%
}

{\tracingmacros1 \tracingonline1
\dec{5}
}
\bye
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent description!

Comment: @JayLee I just added a version without `\x` (so is expandable as has no assignments)

Comment: @DavidCharlisle Can you please elaborate on the "as has no assignments" part? I can understand the code, thank you.

Comment: @JayLee `\message{\dec{6}}`  works in the last version as it only uses expansion. It fails in the versions with `\x=#1` as assignments do not happen in such a context

Comment: @DavidCharlisle Ahha, I now get it. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

Via the last `#1` in the `\else`-branch of `\dec` TeX in the memory accumulates the tokens `\number\x` rather than results of evaluating `\number\x` (which in each iteration would give another result). When all the accumulated `\number\x` get evaluated after the last iteration, the value of `\x` is 0.

In order to make more obvious what is happening, let's evaluate the argument via `\expandafter` and `\number` before via `\exchange` placing the evaluation-result at the end of the `\else`-branch/right before the closing `\fi`:

```tex
\newcount\x

\long\def\exchange#1#2{#2#1}

\def\dec#1{%
  \ifnum#1=0
    .%
  \else
    #1%
    \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\number#1}{%
      \x=#1
      \advance\x by-1
      \dec{\number\x}%
    }%
  \fi%
}
\dec{5}

\bye
```

This code is only to exhibit what the problen with the code of the question is.

For practical use the code provided by David Carlisle in his answer is much better.